# Getting Firebase exception from nowhere

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

My Xamarin.Android app worked fine with Firebase all the time. Now I have the following exception from nowhere, when I try to "order" the device-specific firebase token.

The exception message is:

> Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process
>   de.myapplication.android.  Make sure to call
>   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

I never needed this call before, but I did what the exception told me:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);

    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    var msgListenerIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyFirebaseMessagingService));
    StartService(msgListenerIntent);

    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

Calling the initalizing method does not change the problem. The last few weeks, ordering the token worked totally fine.

Note: Sometimes, Visual Studio wants to change the ***ResourceDesigner.cs*** file. It wants to remove the following lines:

```
// aapt resource value: 0x7f080051
public const int default_web_client_id = 2131230801;

// aapt resource value: 0x7f080052
public const int firebase_database_url = 2131230802;

// aapt resource value: 0x7f08004f
public const int gcm_defaultSenderId = 2131230799;

// aapt resource value: 0x7f080053
public const int google_api_key = 2131230803;

// aapt resource value: 0x7f080050
public const int google_app_id = 2131230800;

// aapt resource value: 0x7f080054
public const int google_crash_reporting_api_key = 2131230804;

// aapt resource value: 0x7f080055
public const int google_storage_bucket = 2131230805;
```

Could it be a hint for me that visual studio wants to delete those lines?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug from Xamarin.
References:

- http://xamarin21.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=23562832&item=46695
- https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56108